# Angular + Firebase three way binding sync and network bandwidth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, bandwidth

I wanted to sync the text box content to different clients through `Angular + Firebase`.
I have doubt that whenever i type each letter, will the firebase sync with the database?

Will it affect the network bandwidth? Basically How it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AngularFire's 3-way data binding (i.e. the $firebase(ref).$bind method), then each letter you type will be synced with Firebase. The bandwidth requirement will scale with each keystroke.

If bandwidth is a concern and you don't want synchronization per keystroke, there are a couple of other options:

- Use explicit bindings with AngularFire that only sync to Firebase when you call certain methods like $set() or $save()
- Use a OT library like Firepad that implements granular collaborative text editing: http://www.firepad.io